# Should I use 2 different test sets for variable selection and measuring performance?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, cross-validation, feature-selection

I am an undergraduate student who has recently been introduced to ML. I have a doubt regarding the usage of test sets and I was wondering if you could help me with it.

Let's say I want to compare 2 different ML techniques in terms of prediction accuracy (test error). I understand that one common approach is to randomly divide the data into a train set (say 80% of the data) and a test set (the remaining 20%). Hence, I should fit the models on the train set and assess their prediction accuracy on the test set. Everything seemed clear to me until that point.

However, what would happen if one of these ML techniques involved variable selection? 
In that case, I was thinking about dividing the train set (80%) into a second train set (say, 60%) and a second test set (20%). Then, the next step would be to fit all the different models of this ML technique (with different variables) on the second train set (60%), then assessing their performance on the second test set (20%), in order to choose the best model (hence, performing variable selection). After this, I would fit the chosen model into the first train set (80%) and compare its performance against the other ML technique.

Is this a valid approach? If not, what would you suggest?
Thanks in advance, I would appreciate any help. Sorry if my English might sound odd, but it is not my native language